# How to pass Dask dataframe as input to dask-ml models?

Tags: python, dask, dask-ml

Usual ML pipelines involve processing pandas or dask dataframes into a form that can be passed into ML models. Many dask-ml models, however, cannot accept Dask dataframes because they do not track the number of rows per partition. Calling the `fit` method throws a `Cannot fit on dask.dataframe due to unknown partition lengths error`. What should I do so that I can pass a Dask dataframes to a dask-ml model?

Here is an example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask_ml.cluster import KMeans

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                                  'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}),
                    npartitions=2)

kmeans = KMeans()
kmeans.fit(df)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-6c1545864b12> in <module>()
      6 
      7 kmeans = KMeans()
----> 8 kmeans.fit(df)

~/anaconda3/envs/pds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_ml/cluster/k_means.py in fit(self, X, y)
    187 
    188     def fit(self, X, y=None):
--> 189         X = self._check_array(X)
    190         labels, centroids, inertia, n_iter = k_means(
    191             X,

~/anaconda3/envs/pds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_ml/utils.py in wraps(*args, **kwargs)
    298         def wraps(*args, **kwargs):
    299             with _timer(f.__name__, _logger=logger, level=level):
--> 300                 results = f(*args, **kwargs)
    301             return results
    302 

~/anaconda3/envs/pds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_ml/cluster/k_means.py in _check_array(self, X)
    159         elif isinstance(X, dd.DataFrame):
    160             raise TypeError(
--> 161                 "Cannot fit on dask.dataframe due to unknown " "partition lengths."
    162             )
    163 

TypeError: Cannot fit on dask.dataframe due to unknown partition lengths.
```

Comment: I recommend providing a small minimal example.

Comment: @MRocklin I've added an example

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports .  Not required obviously, but anything you can do to make it easier for question answerers improves the odds that they'll spend their time helping you.

Comment: @MRocklin replaced example with MCVE

Comment: Thanks: https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now supported on dask-ml master with https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/pull/393

That will be included in the Dask-ML 0.10 release.